# partclone.btrfs thousands of correctable csum errors

Tags: btrfs, disk-cloning

I just cloned a btrfs file system from one disk to another using `partclone.btrfs --dev-to-dev`. Afterwards, I mounted the cloned file system and started a scrub to see if everything is in order. After a while I checked the status and was shocked to see hundreds of thousands of correctable csum errors. Should I be worried? Since they are correctable errors, I guess it's OK, but still. Is this an expected result of the cloning? I'm using Oracle Linux 6, i.e. kernel 3.8.13.

Thanks for any insight in advance.

Comment: Have you performed a scrub on the source disk too? I'd definitely be concerned. You should probably build the latest kernel and btrfs-progs and try again...

Comment: @HoJi No, I haven't checked the source disk. Good idea. I'll do that and report back.

Comment: @HoJi I scrubbed the source disk. It checks out OK. 0 errors. I also compared some of the cloned files with sha256sum, they are all identical.

Comment: Hmm... It could well be a bug in btrfs in that case. The best course of action is to compile yourself the latest kernel version and btrfs-progs - if the problem still exists then post the details to the btrfs mailing list. The 3.8 kernel is pretty old now from a btrfs point of view, as I'm assuming the userspace tools are the same age too.

Comment: I've seen this same behaviour on linux 6.6 with partclone.btrfs v0.3.27 (0882b2de94f05d3ad81304872cbd3dff02105239)